# Unnexpected 'foreach' in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, foreach

I am creating a tcpdf and it runs but throws an "Unnexpected 'foreach'" error.

The code is:

```
foreach ($details as $row) {

                    $dt .= "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row->w_name . "</td>
                            <td>" . foreach($detl as $rok){ if( ($rok->worker_id==$row->worker_id) && ($found_dats_val1[0]==$rok->date)){ echo $rok->total_amount; } } . "</td>
                            <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[1] . "</td>
                            <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[2] . "</td>
                            <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[3] . "</td>
                           </tr>";
            }
```

I want to print the " $rok->total_amount " in second 'td' but Unnexpected 'foreach error show in that column how to I write foreach in the above 'td'? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't run a `foreach` while creating a string - you've to separate this here.

> PHP's foreach section is well explained.
>
> You should carefully study the docs. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php).

A possible solution would be

```
foreach ($details as $row) 
{
    $dt .= "
     <tr>
        <td>" . $row->w_name . "</td>
        <td>";
        foreach($detl as $rok)
        { 
            if( ($rok->worker_id==$row->worker_id) && ($found_dats_val1[0]==$rok->date))
            { 
                $dt .= $rok->total_amount; 
            } 
        } 
    $dt .= "</td>
        <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[1] . "</td>
        <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[2] . "</td>
        <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[3] . "</td>
     </tr>"
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not the way to concat your content. Try this

```
foreach ($details as $row) {

    $dt .= "<tr><td>" . $row->w_name . "</td>";
    $dt .= "<td>";
            foreach($detl as $rok){
                if( ($rok->worker_id==$row->worker_id) && ($found_dats_val1[0]==$rok->date)){ 
                    $dt .= $rok->total_amount; 
                } 
            }
    $dt .= "</td>
    <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[1] . "</td>
    <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[2] . "</td>
    <td>" .  $found_dats_val1[3] . "</td>
   </tr>";
}
```